# OpenCV-Face Recognition-How to take image as an input

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, face-recognition

I'm working on opencv with C++ on Ubuntu. I have code for face detection.. but I want to take an image as an input and track/recognize that face in the live video from the webcam. Could anyone please tell me how to proceed or post code. please!

Comment: Did you checkout OpenCV documentation and sample? Like this one: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture

Comment: Yes,but thats all about capturing video.. I want code for giving an image as an input..

Comment: You mean loading say, a BMP, PNG or JPG? Will imread do? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

Comment: Yes,after loading the image..I need to detect the face in the image in the live video captured from webcam.

Comment: you mean like this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Comment: I could do the above.. but that's only detecting a face. I want to recognise a face!

Comment: would this help? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html